# How to exit from plpgsql function while returning query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In a plpgsql function how can I return a query and return from the function itself? If I just do `return query select ...` the statement after gets executed as well, so the `return` doesn't actually return from the whole function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just `return;` as a single statement, example:

```
create or replace function my_func()
returns setof int language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return query select generate_series(1,2);
    return;
    return query select generate_series(3,4);
end $$;

select my_func();

 my_func 
---------
       1
       2
(2 rows)
```